# before_destroy not firing with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to delete all records of group_maps which are associated with the group that is destroyed. [In the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), it says

> If the :through option is used, then the join records are destroyed instead, not the objects themselves.

Im confused.

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :group_maps
  has_many :users, :through => :group_maps

  before_destroy :destroy_group_maps

  def destroy_group_maps
    self.group_maps.delete_all
  end

end
```

[image: rails c output]

**EDIT 1:**
By the way, I've tried adding , `:dependent => destroy` 
and
`:dependent => delete_all` as well. None of them have worked.

**EDIT 2:**
**group_maps_controller.rb**

```
class GroupMapsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    GroupMap.find[params[:id]].destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: try, `self.group_maps.destroy_all`

Comment: Thanks for comment, it doesn't work as well. Is the problem that I don't have `destroy` method in **groups_controller.rb** ? If so, what should I put into `destroy` method ?

Comment: no destroy method is not an issue, have you added dependent destroy like thoi? `has_many :group_maps, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: if you are trying in console, __restart the rails console__

Comment: Oh, thank you! That WAS the problem. Restarting the console has worked like a charm. Also, I can use `has_many :group_maps, :dependent => :destroy` and it also works! Can you convert your answer to comment so that I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling a `before_destroy` to destroy the associations, you can add a **`dependent: :destroy`** to delete them.

**`dependent: :destroy` deletes the associated record, once the parent record is deleted.**

I prefer using `dependent: :destroy` instead of `before_destroy`

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :group_maps, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :group_maps

  before_destroy :destroy_group_maps

  def destroy_group_maps
    self.group_maps.delete_all
  end

end
```

Comment: @Nerzid, added as an answer. Glad to help you. :)

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was about restarting the rails console ^_^.

Comment: yes, but using `dependent: :destroy` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

In your `destroy_group_maps` method, type:

```
def destroy_group_maps
  self.group_maps.each { |group_map| group_map.destroy }
end
```